# Heroku: Your connection is not private: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku

I have a heroku hosted app that is throwing the

```
Your connection is not private
error (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)
```

but it only occurs on a cell phone.  In a web browser, the page loads with https without a problem (I am using google chrome and the chrome app).

I have been using the free SSL certificate that Heroku provides for a couple months with no issue but I noticed this error today.

Has anyone seen this / know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: How old is the cellphone, and what type?

Comment: Facing the exct same issue. Did you find the solution? My app is working fine on my mobile, but on my PC, its flagged not secure with NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: @anandhu I wish I remember... my apologies.  Best of luck.